# Cutting a part of .avi file is not accurate, if output is specified as .avi file (but if output is specified as .mp4 file, it is)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to cut a part of **.avi** file using the command

`ffmpeg -ss 346 -i input.avi -t 5 -c copy -y output.avi`

The total length of the output video is about 13 seconds, which is 8 seconds longer than needed. But if extension of the output file is specified as **.mp4**, then cutting is accurate. I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVI and MP4 are containers for streams of data, MP4 being far more capable.

The MP4 container allows you to create accurate "cuts" from a source video stream at non-keyframes, without re-encoding, by internally using an [edit list](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/QuickTime_container#elst).

For example, say you want to copy from your source video 346s–351s seconds (which is what it looks like you're doing). If the closest keyframe before 346s is at 338s then ffmpeg actually copies the video starting at 338s but uses MP4's edit list magic to tell media players to skip the first 8 seconds.

The same logic *might* also apply to the end of a cut (not sure, would have to test). If so, the edit list would also tell media players to stop playing earlier.

AVI does not support edit lists like MP4 does, which is why with the AVI container you will see the full 13 second cut.

I hope this makes sense - do leave a comment if you have questions and I will try to clarify.

**Edit** I have created a diagram to try to visually show what ffmpeg is doing:

[image: How ffmpeg does cuts when you're not re-encoding]

Comment: Thank you, Michael, it became clearer for me. But there’s still one thing that I don’t understand. When I run `ffmpeg -ss 346 -i input.avi -t 5 -c copy -y output.mp4`, ffmpeg converts my AVI file to MP4 file. But I don’t understand what happens in the background. It seems to me that ffmpeg doesn’t convert the whole file, because this command executes in a very small time. But if only the cut-out part is converted, how did ffmpeg manage to create “cuts” at non-key frames? Sorry, I’m a newbie in working with videos.

Comment: In your command ,ffmpeg locates the nearest keyframe before the cutpoint and starts copying from there.

Comment: @jane Gyan's comment is spot on. And you are right too - ffmpeg doesn't copy the entire video stream. But it has to start at a keyframe. So it picks the nearest keyframe before your cutpoint and starts copying from there. Then, in the MP4 container, it creates an "edit list" which tells media players how much of the beginning of the video stream to ignore. Put another way - your MP4 is "faking" a 5 second clip because internally it actually has 13 seconds of video in it.

Comment: @jane I've created a diagram to help you visualize what ffmpeg is doing, it's in my updated answer :-)

Comment: @Michal Cihelka Thank you! Now I’ve got it. May I ask you one more question related to this topic somewhere ?

Comment: @jane Sure - would you like to create a new question for it? Or if it's a short question directly related to this maybe just ask it in a comment

Comment: @Michal Cihelka, it was quite long, so I've created another question:  https://superuser.com/questions/1643484/fast-and-relatively-accurate-cutting-from-a-video