# Fast and relatively accurate cutting from a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m trying to build an application, which cuts specific small sections from videos. To be more precise, it cuts out what the person is saying according to the timestamps in the subtitles. Cutting with the following command

`ffmpeg -ss 346 -i input.avi -t 5 -c copy -y output.mp4`

is very fast and accurate enough, but I'm not sure that it is memory-effecient due to the "faking" that MP4 performs. I’ve also tried cutting with the following command:

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss 346 -t 5 -c copy output.mp4`

In this case, ffmpeg can cut at non-keyframes, so videos often don't play properly at the beginning, which is critical for me.

I was trying to avoid decoding and encoding because my application has to process multiple videos at a time, so it might be too slow this way. I've already thought about forcing ffmpeg to make a keyframe at the beginning of the required section and then use the first command, but I'm not sure if that would be fast. As far as I'm concerned, making keyframes is not an easy operation. And my top priorities are time-efficiency and relative accuracy. So now I don’t know which of these options works best for my case. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have a moment before I have to run off so I'll make this quick (and edit later if necessary).

I would take this approach - my "philosophy". For any given problem, look first to a solution that gives the desired result. It might not be the most efficient or clean solution, but if it gives the desired result then by definition it is a good solution.

And you almost answered your own question. If I may quote you:

> my top priorities are time-efficiency and relative accuracy.

I'm glad you know your priorities! So, that said, are you happy to trade a bit of file size to meet these priorities? If so, then go with your first example. As you say, it's very quick, it's accurate enough, and the only cost is a bit of file size.

Hope this helps :-) M

Comment: Your philosophy is great! I think the first solution will work for me. But I’m doing some kind of research work. So I'd like to know if there's a more efficient way to perform this task (or maybe I'm wrong with the conclusions I made)

Comment: @jane Thank you (although my philosophy does have unintended consequences sometimes, hmm...) Cutting from a video stream, by copying rather than re-encoding, is by far the most efficient and it maintains full quality of the original source - even if ffmpeg has to copy from keyframes and generate the *edit list* it's still lightning fast and will always be faster than re-encoding or generating new keyframes.

Comment: @jane I just thought of a potentially ideal solution. I just don't know how to implement it. Say you have a 2-hour long AVI video and you want to cut it into 2,000 pieces. You could just make 2,000 "playlist" files that reference the original AVI file. If you were happy to restrict playback to VLC Media Player, you could create XSPF playlist files with start-time/stop-time values that VLC understands. Examples are here: https://wiki.videolan.org/XSPF/

Comment: It’s a really interesting approach! Unfortunately, I have to cut sections from different videos at a time :( By the way, in your previous answer you said that MP4 is far more capable than AVI. I know little about containers, so is it convenient to make use of MP4 here? Or maybe there’s still a better option?

Comment: @jane Ah I see, but I'm glad you have an approach that does what you need. MP4 is just fine, but I generally use the Matroska (MKV) container because it supports a wider range of video/audio formats. It used to be that MKV was not as widely used (or recognized by some media players) but these days it's on par with MP4. For the work you're doing MP4 is totally fine. Of course, there's nothing wrong with trying MKV :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!